# Reassigning dataframe rows or variables with iloc returns NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, variable-assignment

I have a "dataframe A" that is partially complete; some rows are missing data.  The missing data can be found on rows in another "dataframe B" (with the same labels, but not position).

When I try to reassign the rows of dataframe A, python returns NaN for all the rows I tried to reassign.

I have tried:
  iloc
  iloc specifying the columns
  iloc after making column names match
  iloc on deep copy
  converting the target column into different dtypes e.g. string, float

## First attempt, returns dfA with NaN in all columns of rows A1:A2

```
dfA.iloc[A1:A2] = dfB.iloc[B1:B2]
```

## Second attempt, returns dfA with NaN in column 2 of rows A1:A2

```
dfA.iloc[A1:A2, 2] = dfB.iloc[B1:B2, 2]
```

## Third attempt, same issue

```
dfA_copy = copy.deepcopy(dfA)
dfA_copy.iloc[A1:A2]
```

[dfA_copy rows A1:A2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0isW.png)

```
dfB_copy = copy.deepcopy(dfB)
dfB_copy.iloc[B1:B2]
```

[dfB_copy rows B1:B2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDEWj.png)

```
dfA_copy.iloc[A1:A2] = dfB_copy.iloc[B1:B2]
```

[deep copy reassignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3vxn.png)

I expected the data from "dataframe B" to replace the missing data in "dataframe A".

Comment: are there any key columns you could join the data on and then set the columns in dfA equal to the columsn in dfB that you need?

Comment: good idea, will try that right now and update. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have the two pandas dataframe in the same shape then you can do something like this

```
dfA[dfA.isnull()] = dfB
```

If this solves your question, please accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks, however they are not the same size.  dfB only contains the data that dfA is missing.  dfA contains other information too

Comment: Can you update your question with sample input and output?